# How i can make a button ,from a page , to automatically trigger a specific button from another page?

Tags: javascript, button

I am building a project for school and I encounter a problem . I made an ecommerce website ,and in the **store** page I created the **cart** on the bottom . now when I click the the product button it's added in the cart . Now i created a page for each product with description and I have an ***Add to cart*** button there too , how can I click on that button and that automatically go on **store** page and click the specific button for the product?

here is my store code :

```
<img class="shop-item-image" src="imaginiproduse/p1.jpg">
<span class="shop-item-title">Busuioc</span>
<div class="shop-item-details">
      <span class="shop-item-price">$12.99</span>
      <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button " type="button" >ADD TO CART</button> <-- HERE IS THE BUTTON 
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my individual product page code :

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="../imaginiproduse/p1.jpg" style="max-width: 250px;" >
    <div class="text">
        <h2>Busuioc</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum nesciunt explicabo omnis dolores, sunt odio ducimus consequuntur distinctio quo et nemo molestiae saepe nostrum a iste! Modi amet ab dolore.</p>               
    </div>
    <p><button  type="button">ADD TO CART</button></p> <--- HERE IS MY OTHER BUTTON     
</div>
```

Comment: Why dont you just add an `<a/.>` link  ?

Comment: How can that help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated you have options and typically this would be done with cookies (secure cookies if its sensitive stuff )sidenote too, cookie are not always server-side and can be set on the client and read by the client OR server so it works both ways, localstorage (only read by the browser, but is persistent) or server-side sessions, server cookies (would render on the server and generate links etc)

Now with that said it seems more like you are doing this via the client side and using localStorage at the moment.

How you have your question worded is a bit confusing, but if I understand correctly you basically want to store the 'add to cart' with the item, so they can view the card, see their item and then also click back to their item from the cart etc.

The flow of that, using localStorage could be

1. User views the item detail page
2. User clicks add to cart --> This triggers a function to append the itemID to the cart localstorage ( localStorage can only be a string, so you would end up stringifying your object before storing it ) possibly somthing like

```js
//click action (jquery syntax)
$('.addToCart').on("click",()=>{
//add to cart clicked
//Grab localStorage first
let data = localStorage.getItem('cart');
//check if there is anything in it, otherwise don't stringigy
if ( data !== undefined && data !== "")
{
//Means there is an actual localStorage object called cart AND its not empty
//we can then proceed with stringifying it 
try{
//turn the localStorage into an object
data = JSON.parse(data);
//now that you have the object you will push the item ID to the array
data.push(itemID);
}catch(e){
//yikes, its not valid JSON
console.error(e)
}


}

})
```

I have not tested the code but it gives you an idea of the flow, then removing an item can just be a simple pop of the item.

When viewing it, you just pull the localStorage item, convert to an array and loop over it. You can also store more items in the object too, things like name, id, price etc OR you can run the idea against an API call etc.

Comment: Thanks man ! this is giving me an overall perspective , now i understand it better .

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding elements to the cart and storing items in the cart?

if you are using vanilla javaScript and storing cart items in an array, you can not do that.

You have to store cart items in a way that is accessible through pages. For example:

- you can use cookies (server side)
- you can use HTML5 local file storage (client side. temporary)
- use some sate management package like redux (may need nodejs)

Comment: ok I think I might did it with local storage but how can i connect the button from products page to add also in the cart?

Comment: You can read from the file in the to show added items in the cart.
and write to enlist items in the cart.

you can access file form any page.

Comment: I don't quite understand , if you have any refrence , please give me the link .